# y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (234, 3) instead. how to solve this?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

'y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (234, 3) instead.'

```
data = dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
label = dataset.iloc[:,-1].values
 
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()


from sklearn.svm import SVC
classifier = SVC(kernel="linear",random_state=0)
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred=classifier.predict(X_test)
```

detail code, idk what i can do

```
label = label_binarize(label, classes=[0, 1, 2])
n_classes=label.shape[1]
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(data_full,label,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)

classif= OneVsRestClassifier(classifier)
y_score = classif.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)
```

'this error'

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
model = SVC(kernel="linear",random_state=0)
model.fit(X_train,y_train) //this error
```

[linkcode](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qDXGf5IPzGfj0e_kmiyhwricpsFpoO3M?usp=sharing)

Comment: It's expecting only one column in `y_train` and you have three

Comment: how do i change to 1 column? i do te iloc things but nothing change. same error

Answer (score 1):

Your y (which is "label" variable) must be a 1d array means it must be just 1 column of your dataset.
But you pick 3 columns for it. It should be like this:

```
Label = dataset["name or index of the column "]
```

Comment: thanks its solved